# How can I exclude certain columns from import into Power BI

Tags: sql-server, import, powerbi

I need to import multiple tables from a SQL Server database into Power BI, but I would like to avoid importing certain unnecessary columns from many (most) of the tables. Is there any kind of filter or query that can be performed prior to import by listing the columns to exclude?

The only mechanism to accomplish this that I have found is to import everything, and then remove the unwanted columns. This is not really acceptable, since that would involve manual steps for each table, and I have over 500 tables to deal with.

Comment: If you are importing 500 tables to a *single* report, I'd suggest something has gone quite wrong.

Comment: Suggest looking at PowerQuery within Power BI, where you can select/remove columns with ease. If this is obvious to you then update your questi9n with more details.